# How can you get the position and value from a row in an exact cover matrix for sudoku?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, matrix, multidimensional-array

Using an exact cover matrix of sudoku such as the one [here](https://www.stolaf.edu//people/hansonr/sudoku/exactcovermatrix.htm), each row in the matrix correlates to a position in the sudoku grid (row, column) and a value.

Given only the row number in the cover matrix, and the size of the sudoku grid (in that case 9), what is an algorithm for determining the row, column and value that the row refers to? (for example, row 1 refers to row 1, column 1 and value 1, row 12 refers to row 1, column 2, value 3)

Comment: Can you also include in your post what you have tried, searched and, researched so far?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist
We can better assist you if you can narrow down the problem or share with us a reproducible example.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in java which does solve the problem, however I am still curious if there is any way to do this without using a loop, it feels like a problem that could be expressed purely in math to me.

```
private int[] rowInGrid(int puzzleSize, int matrixRow) {
        // return the row, column and value correlating to a row in the cover matrix

        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        int val = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < matrixRow; i++) {
            val++;

            if (val == puzzleSize) {
                col++;
                val = 0;
            }

            if (col == puzzleSize) {
                row++;
                col = 0;
            }
        }

        return new int[]{row,col,val};
    }
```

The function takes the puzzle size (width/height/number of values) and the row number in the cover matrix (eg 0 refers to the first possible value in the first row and first column of the board) and returns the position on the board and the value. This function is all 0 indexed.